# Python csv.writer - is it possible to write to a variable?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use csv.writer to write data to a variable rather than a file?

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
data = ''
csv.writer(data)
# ...... (I have removed the csv processing code for brevity)
message = EmailMessage('Invoice for 2012', 'h', 'noreply@test.co.uk', ['test@test.co.uk'])
message.attach('invoice.csv', data, 'text/csv')
message.send()
```

When I execute the code I get the following error:

```
   argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

Comment: You need to give us the full traceback; that'll give us a much better idea what causes the exception.

Comment: Also, the csv processing code that was removed looks like it could be what causes the problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `csv.writer` class needs a file-like object, something with a `.write()` method. A [`StringIO` class](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) would be best here:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

data = StringIO()
csv.writer(data)
# write your stuff
message = EmailMessage('Invoice for 2012', 'h', 'noreply@test.co.uk', ['test@test.co.uk'])
message.attach('invoice.csv', data.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
message.send()
```

I used the C-variant of the `StringIO` module there; the advantage is speed, the disadvantage that you can use each instance only as a writable *or* a readable file. Since all you do is write to it before retrieving the written data, that's just fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) whenever you need a file-like object (with a `write` method) and do not want to create an actual file in the filesystem.

An advantage of this *memory-file* approach is that I/O is much faster than with a real storage backend. If you want to be even faster, you can use [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO). Note that `cStringIO` is not always available, so you could do something like

```
try:
    import cStringIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    import StringIO
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.x and 2.6+

`cStringIO` as described in the other answers has been removed in Python 3.

Instead use [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.StringIO) like this:

```
import csv
import io

mem_file = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(mem_file)

writer.writerow(['your', 'data', 'here'])

print(mem_file.getvalue())
```

> your,data,here