# Adding a custom attachment (In-memory file with StringIO) to fastapi-mail

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm new to fastapi (and python in general) and am strugling to send an in-memory file as attachment using fastapi-mail.

I'm writing a CSV file in memory using String IO like so:

```
file: io.StringIO = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
writer.writerow(['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3'])
writer.writerow(['Afghanistan', 652090, 'AF', 'AFG'])
```

and attempting to send like so:

```
my_attachment = StreamingResponse(file.getvalue(), media_type="text/csv", headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=daily_stats.csv'})
message = MessageSchema(
    subject="my subject",
    recipients=["mail@mail.mail"],
    body="not working",
    subtype="text",
    attachments=[my_attachment]
)

fm = FastMail(myconf) # ConnectionConfig specified elsewhere
await fm.send_message(message)
```

But it's exploding with this error:

```
File "pydantic/main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init_
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for MessageSchema
attachments -> 0
   instance of UploadFile expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=UploadFile)
attachments -> 0
   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
attachments -> 0
   str type expected (type=type_error.str)
```

it seems to be relatively straight forward in some other smtp clients (e.g. [Python csv.writer - is it possible to write to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228699/python-csv-writer-is-it-possible-to-write-to-a-variable)) but I'm stuck with the fast api one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to figure it out... The solution was actually quite simple, but it was partly guesswork due to the very limited documentation on UploadFile.

anyway, after creating the file:

```
file: io.StringIO = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
writer.writerow(['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3'])
writer.writerow(['Afghanistan', 652090, 'AF', 'AFG'])
```

I simply had to create my own instance of UploadFile based on io.StringIO and pass that. And of course had to make sure to 'rewind' the file to the start:

```
file.seek(0);
upload_file = UploadFile(filename="myfile", file=file, content_type="text/csv");
message = MessageSchema(
    subject="my subject",
    recipients=["mail@mail.mail"],
    body="not working",
    subtype="html",
    attachments=[upload_file]
    )

fm = FastMail(conf)
await fm.send_message(message)
```

And that was it.. Hope someone else finds this useful